# R not colouring bar plot

Tags: r, plot

I am doing a graphical visualization of various parts of my questionnaire.
We are using the RGB system to coordinate colours with Excel
However my bar plots aren't being coloured, only the first colour of the colouring vector is being used.

So instead of

```
barplot(c(1, 1, 1), axes=T, col=c("#806000","#C6E0B4","#FFC000"),names.arg=c("test1","test2","test3"))
```

I am ending up with all three bars being the colour "#806000".

Here is the code for my graph (DATA_tot is the entire data table for my questionnaire):

```
barplot(
  cbind(
    length(which(DATA_tot$A014_18==2)),
    length(which(DATA_tot$A014_02==2)),   
    length(which(DATA_tot$A014_01==2)),
    length(which(DATA_tot$A014_03==2))
    ),
  main="Frage 4a",
  col=c("grey","#806000","#C6E0B4","#FFC000"),
  ylab="Anzahl der Betriebe",
  names.arg=c("keine \n Änderungen","Streuwiesen","einmähdige \n 
Wiesen","Hutweiden"), 
  ylim=c(0,1400),
  cex.axis=0.8, cex.names=0.6
  )
```

Has anybody ever experienced this problem or found a way around it?
I am explicitly looking for solutions with `barplot` (for other reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `c` instead of `cbind`:

```
barplot(
  c(
    length(which(DATA_tot$A014_18==2)),
    length(which(DATA_tot$A014_02==2)),   
    length(which(DATA_tot$A014_01==2)),
    length(which(DATA_tot$A014_03==2))
    ),
  main="Frage 4a",
  col=c("grey","#806000","#C6E0B4","#FFC000"),
  ylab="Anzahl der Betriebe",
  names.arg=c("keine \n Änderungen","Streuwiesen","einmähdige \n 
Wiesen","Hutweiden"), 
  ylim=c(0,1400),
  cex.axis=0.8, cex.names=0.6
  )
```

Comment: An aside to my previous question: How do I label every bar with its height?